# Trigger not able to initialise variable

Tags: oracle, triggers, auditing

I have trigger for auditing, which stored the action performed on any row of EMP table.

This trigger works fine, except in some cases (which occurs very rarely, and  I cannot identify exact condition) it gives me

Oracle Error: **ORA-01400:** cannot insert NULL into ("MY_SCHEMA"."HIST_EMP"."ACTION")

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER HIST_EMP_AIUD 
 AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT OR DELETE
 ON EMP
 REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
 FOR EACH ROW
 DECLARE
      v_action VARCHAR2(1) := 'D';
 BEGIN
      IF INSERTING THEN
           v_action := 'A';
      ELSIF UPDATING THEN
           v_action := 'U';
      END IF;

      IF DELETING THEN
         INSERT INTO hist_emp (source_rowid, source_date, action)
                     VALUES (:old.rowid, SYSDATE, v_action);
      ELSIF INSERTING OR UPDATING THEN
         INSERT INTO hist_emp (source_rowid, source_date, action)
                    VALUES (:new.rowid, SYSDATE, v_action);
      END IF;
EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
        --Code to Log
        -- <some exception handling should be placed here >

END;
```

This generally happens when I am deleting the row, but I am not sure.
Any thought  on why this will be happening? The code looks ok to me...

Comment: Wow, that is strange.  Code looks OK.  Is there actually any code in the "exception when others" clause?  I hope so. can you show it?

Comment: Are there any triggers on `hist_emp`?

Comment: No triggers on `hist_emp`. In When OTHERS section there is an generics procedure call which ultimately makes a insert in a  exception_logging table.

Answer (score 1):

Something weird is going on with variable `v_action` initialization, I guess. Try handling all 3 possibilities:

```
      v_action:= null;
      IF INSERTING THEN
           v_action := 'A';
      ELSIF UPDATING THEN
           v_action := 'U';
      ELSIF DELETING THEN
           v_action := 'D';
      END IF;
```

Comment: @Aditya , Yeah, default v_action VARCHAR2(1) := 'D' is not working in some cases. Try as David suggested...